# autoregressive neural network with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, plot, neuralnetwork

I am trying to draw an autoregressive NN with tikz but i am quite stuck. This is what i've done so far:

```
\tikzset{%
  every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=1cm
  },
  neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=4,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]

\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,missing,3}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {,2,3,4}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (hidden-\m) at (2,2-\y*1.25) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,missing,3}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (output-\m) at (4,2.5-\y) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,p}
  \draw [<-] (input-\i) -- ++(-1,0)
    node [above, midway] {$y_{t-\l}$};


\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,}
  \draw [->] (output-\i) -- ++(1,0)
    node [above, midway] {$y_t$};

\foreach \i in {1,...,3}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,4}
    \draw [->] (input-\i) -- (hidden-\j);

\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,1}
    \draw [->] (hidden-\i) -- (output-\j);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: my nn]

As you can see, i get some errors but the structure is similar to what i am looking for, which is exactly this:
[image: goal nn]

If anyone could help me, i'd really appreciate. I'm quite new on tikz but willing to learn.
Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The output doesn't matter when there are compilation errors. Your first task is to understand and fix the errors. Simplify the code as much as necessary for you to get rid of all errors. Then add things little by little to converge towards your goal, making sure every time you add something that it compiles with no error. The beginning `\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,missing,3} ...` doesn't make much sense: what is the `\l` variable used for here? Also, the first error I get is `Package pgf Error: No shape named \`output-2' is known.` The cause is quite obvious

Comment: from your code: it doesn't define this node. Why don't you fix it? Finally, please start by providing a *complete* (yet minimal) document. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. This would show a minimum of respect and save a lot of time for those who try to help you.

Comment: Regarding the error `No shape named \`output-2' is known`, the value `2` comes from `\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,}`: as there are two elements here, `\i` contains `1` during the first iteration, then `2` during the second iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a complete solution, please find some **debugging-analysis** of your code, and some **observations**.

I added the `arrows.meta` library, so the arrow tips will turn out a bit better. Marked below as comments. // I introduced arrow-`styles` for your `\draw` statements, leaving some color intentionally to support debugging. Please remove later. Your current `stealth` statement might be obsolete or wihtout effect. // I entered some comments to better structure the code, like `% input layer` . // Some of your problems seem to arise from the `count` option, which might be obsolete when done differently. At least the loop index, like `\m`, and the counter, like `\y`, differ often enough. // In the connections from and to the `hidden-layer` the counter has to start at 2, not 1, in your approach.

This is my result, from the code below. Please find observations after the code.

[image: compiled result]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% to change the arrow tip

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=1cm
  },
  neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=4,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
  },
  % arrow styles; color fordebugging
  arr1/.style={-{Stealth}, orange},
  arr2/.style={{Stealth}-, brown}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]

% input layer
\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,missing,3}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};

% hidden layer
\foreach \m [count=\y] in {,2,3,4}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (hidden-\m) at (2,2-\y*1.25) {};

% output layer
\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,missing,3}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (output-\m) at (4,2.5-\y) {};


% CONNECTIONS
% inputs
\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,p}
  \draw [arr2] (input-\i) -- ++(-1,0)% <<< arrow style
    node [above, midway] {$y_{t-\l}$};

%output
\foreach \l [count=\i] in { 3}% has to be 3 for a reason I don't understand
  \draw [arr1] (output-\i) -- ++(1,0)% <<< arrow style
    node [above, midway] {$y_t$};

% input to hidden
\foreach \i in {1,...,3}
  \foreach \j in {2,...,4}% has to start at 2, not 1
    \draw [->] (input-\i) -- (hidden-\j);

% hidden to output
\foreach \i in {2,...,4}% has to start at 2, not 1
  \foreach \j in {1,...,1}
    \draw [arr1] (hidden-\i) -- (output-\j);% <<< arrow style

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

**Observations**: The unconnected node in the hidden layer is both obsolete and somewhat obscure, when you output the loop variables as node-text. // For the output I'd replace the loop by two simple draw statements. You also don't want the dots there. // I could have used an additional arrow-style to create dashed lines. // Regarding the labels at the connectors, eta is the only one, which could be a label of the line itself. For the other ones it's better to put some nodes, which just place the labels, as you don't want to loop that kind of output.

Comment: thank you so much, it has been very useful!